# horizontal scroll appearing when using col-md-offset

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

when i am using **bootstrap** col-md-offset-2, then the horizontal scroll bar appearing in window view as well as mobile view. I don't know how this horizontal scroll bar appear in my website.

please help me. 
thank you...

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/norwich.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements. All other JS at the end of file. -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->

  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- header -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
          <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="container">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#"><h1>LOGO</h1></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li><a >HOME</a></li>
             <li><a >ABOUT</a></li>
             <li><a >SKIP HIRE</a></li>
             <li><a >CONTACT</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </nav>
</header>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround all your code with

```
<div class="container-fluid"></div>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7dcd13z3/)

Comment: I do not see scroll bars in the JSFiddle unless I remove `<div class="container-fluid">`. Do you mean you still see the scroll bars?

Comment: yes sir, horizontal bar shown on large screen but not a small screen.

Comment: replace `<div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">` with `<div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">`, seems to work: [https://jsfiddle.net/7dcd13z3/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/7dcd13z3/2/)

Comment: You seem to be using a larger monitor, use `col-xl-offset-2 col-xl-8` instead of `col-md-offset-2 col-md-8` then :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi when you dont have a container behind the

```html
<div class="row"></div>
```

It will at a negative margin.

So you can do this instead.

```html
<!-- header -->
          <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse col-md-offset-2 col-md-8" role="navigation">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="container">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#"><h1>LOGO</h1></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
             <li><a >HOME</a></li>
             <li><a >ABOUT</a></li>
             <li><a >SKIP HIRE</a></li>
             <li><a >CONTACT</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
 </nav>
</header>
```